# iOS stack view constraint issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a modal view to display some information. This modal view will cover the whole view as well to prevent interaction with underlying view. My view hierarchy in custom control is as follows:

- Self View (100% of area)

  - Overlay Window (100% of area)

    - StackView (constrain to center of overlay)

      - Title label
      - Subtitle label
      - ... and whatever info

The prototype code works intended as long as there is only one arranged subview in stack view. When there is more than one arranged sub view in stack then display is not centered and overlay itself seems to be positioned wrong. I have added some background colors to verify this behavior. The view looks like below:
[image]

I have posted the prototype code at [prototype gist](https://gist.github.com/byteblocks/9dcaba4a6e8ba50065d1)

I am not even sure if the way I did is the correct way. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want the two colored views share the same width ?

Comment: Yes. The intent is that overlay window is going to cover the whole view to prevent interaction with view below. Blue is background of this view control and green is background color of overlay window on top of it.

Comment: u need to give equal width and height constraints to the subviews of stackview, if you want them to have same sizes

Comment: Whole idea of using stack view is to let subview arrange as pr settings of stack view attributes and not having to add custom constraints. As per settings subviews should be centered along the axis and thats who the properties are set on stack view as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all set now. It seems that adding constraint for height and width anchor for overlay window is not working as I was hoping for. They were setting correct height and width but not positioning it. The frame for overlay had negative origin causing it to go offscreen from left side.
I had to add constraints for leading, trailing, top and bottom anchors to get it to work.

```
func addConstraintsForOverlay(){
    overlayWindow?.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leadingAnchor).active = true
    overlayWindow?.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(trailingAnchor).active = true
    overlayWindow?.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topAnchor).active = true
    overlayWindow?.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomAnchor).active = true
}
```